# Select aninhado MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

Estou tentando pegar o maior valor dentre os menores de uma tabela, a query que estou tentando executar é a seguinte:

```sql
SELECT district FROM
    (SELECT district, MIN(postal_code)
    FROM address
    WHERE postal_code != ''
    GROUP BY district)
WHERE MAX(postal_code);
```

> Erro: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas na sua sentença. Primeiro vou colocar como fica corrigido, depois vou explicar:

```
SELECT district FROM
  (SELECT district, min_postal_code from
    (SELECT district, MIN(postal_code) as min_postal_code
    FROM address
    WHERE postal_code != ''
    GROUP BY district) tabela
   GROUP BY district
   HAVING min_postal_code = MAX(min_postal_code)) tabela2;
```

- *Subselects* precisam ser identificados por um nome. No caso, usei `tabela`;
- Funções de agregação, como `MIN`, não devolvem bons nomes de coluna. Por isso usei `as min_postal_code`;
- `WHERE` requer alguma condição de teste. Apenas `MAX(postal_code)` não testa nada. Coloquei o teste que imagino que você gostaria de fazer, que é pegar o distrito com o maior código postal (outro *subselect*);
- Não sei como o MySQL gerencia tabelas de `SELECT`s aninhados, mas está claro pra mim que o escopo da tabela aninhada não existe dentro de `WHERE`, então aninhei duas vezes usando `HAVING`, que é a condição de testa funções de agregação.

Comment: Tentei executar no phpmyadmin e retornou o seguinte erro: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Tem razão. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Ocorreu um outro problema, ele tenta buscar esta sentença "select MAX(min_postal_code) from tabela" no banco de dados e não na gerada pelo select anterior o que retorna o seguinte erro: #1146 - Table 'sakila.tabela' doesn't exist  onde sakila é o nome da minha base

Comment: Modifiquei novamente. Não ficou muito bonito, mas deve funcionar.

Comment: Desse jeito ai não retorna somente um registro mas todos os menores da tabela address, eu quse consegui pelo codigo antigo porem nao retorna o nome do district:  SELECT district, MAX(tabela.min_postal_code) FROM
    (SELECT district, MIN(postal_code) as min_postal_code
    FROM address
    WHERE postal_code != ''
    GROUP BY district) tabela;

Comment: Sim, tem razão. É que não estou testando sua sentença, então está um pouco difícil imaginar a saída. Veja agora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30281/discussion-between-joao-carlos-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).